# Creating treeview in android

Tags: android, treeview

My requirement is like, I have a webservice url where from I load the datas into tree view. u communicate webservice load all first leve menus. Later when I click on first menu, i again communicate webservice to get the second level node data, my webservice data has an attribute nodetype = "group" or "item" which means if it has sublevels It says group else "item". I can use this to show + or - mark in my treeview. I have gone through the treeview in google Code. They load all the data at once which does not suit my reuquirement. Please need some help on logic building. If any one has already done such thing it would be really great if you can share the code here or mail me at colddropz@gmail.com.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: load data in background using AsyncTask

Comment: Is this your problem?

Comment: Okay. I tried something else.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can study this library: https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView to get your required tree-view. It's a N-level tree with supporting custom styled node. You can use it as following:

1) install: `compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'`

2) build tree-view:

```
 TreeNode tree_root = TreeNode.root(); 
 TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("node-name");
 TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("child-node-name-1");
 TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("child_node-name-2");

 parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
 tree_root.addChild(parent);
```

3) add tree-view to layout:

```
 AndroidTreeView treeView = new AndroidTreeView(getActivity(), tree_root);
 containerView.addView(treeView.getView());
```

You can customize the node-view to show + or - mark in your treeview with extending `TreeNode.BaseNodeViewHolder`